# Can’t access public slots from QtScript

Tags: qt, qt4, qtscript

I have this class:

```
class JavaScript : public QObject {    
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        JavaScript();        
        bool executeFromFile(QString file);  
        bool enabled;

    public slots:
        void setEnabled( bool enabled );
        bool isEnabled() const;    

    private:
        QScriptEngine engine;
};
```

The methods are defined like this:

```
#include "javascript.h"

JavaScript::JavaScript() {  
    executeFromFile("test.js");
}
bool JavaScript::executeFromFile(QString file) {
    QFile scriptFile(file);
    if (!scriptFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) return false;
    QTextStream stream(&scriptFile);
    QString contents = stream.readAll();    
    scriptFile.close();
    engine.evaluate(contents, file);    
    return true;
}

void JavaScript::setEnabled( bool enabled ) {
    JavaScript::enabled = enabled;
}
bool JavaScript::isEnabled() const {
    return enabled;
}
```

I’m trying to access the public slots previously defined in the header file like the documentation says:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/scripting.html#making-a-c-object-available-to-scripts-written-in-qtscript

The test.js file looks like this, just like the examples of the docs:

```
var obj = new JavaScript();
obj.setEnabled( true );
print( "obj is enabled: " + obj.isEnabled() );
```

But i’m not getting anything. It seems it doesn’t find the JavaScript object. What am I missing?

Doing a simple

```
print(1+1)
```

works just fine.

**EDIT:** An [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/script-defaultprototypes.html) in the qt4 webpage implements **Q_PROPERTY**. I tried this, but got the same result:

```
Q_PROPERTY(bool enabled READ isEnabled WRITE setEnabled)
```

**EDIT 1:** Tried implementing the initializer like this:

```
// javascript.h:

JavaScript(QObject *parent = 0);

// javascript.cpp:

JavaScript::JavaScript(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {}
```

Still nothing...

**EDIT 2:** Some examples inherits from `QScriptable` too:

```
class JavaScript : public QObject, public QScriptable {}
```

But that makes no difference either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create QScriptClass instead of QObject. Qt contains example of how to extend script capabilites in Qt. Take a look on [Custom Script Class Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/script-customclass.html)

Comment: I cannot create QScripClass: **error: type ‘QScriptClass’ is not a direct base of ‘JavaScript’
**

Comment: The example link is dead - did you mean this example - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/script-customclass.html ?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are actually missing is adding it to the script engine.

At some point you will have to declare a script engine

`QScriptEngine * engine = new QScriptEngine(this);`

Then you are going to want to add your object to  the engine

```
JavaScript* js= new JavaScript();
QScriptValue jsobj = engine->newQObject(js);
engine->globalObject().setProperty("JavaScript", jsobj );
```

I'm by no means an expert but I think there is something else you need to do to say

`var obj = new JavaScript();`

at that point you probably need to  take Kamil's advice and make `JavaScript` a subclass of `QScriptClass`